# Using sscanf to get two double values from cmd

Tags: scanf

I'm having some issues with sscanf reading two values from cmd. I have this code below:

sscanf(argv[1], "%lf %lf", &m.iMin, &m.iMax);

First value assigns correctly, iMax is always set to zero. It works when used two sscanfs, though. I tried everything I found online, but unsuccesfully. I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What input are you providing? If you are correctly putting a space between the two numbers, you will probably need to wrap the expression in double quotes when invoking

e.g

```
myConsoleApp.exe "100 200"
```

otherwise 100 and 200 are seen as 2 different args.

Comment: Oh, that helped, thank you! So if I get it correctly, it's still one argument, just his parts divided into different storages? What if I wanted to use one sscanf to get 2 doubles and one string? Should I type "1 2 filename.txt" using sscanf(argv[1], "%lf %lf %s", &double1, &double2, string);?

Comment: So when you invoke a console app or batch script, a space is interpreted as the delimiter for a different argument. If your argument has a space in it, it needs to be "escaped" by wrapping the whole expression in double quotes.